# How can I select a range of td's in a table with javascript area selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

I looking for a script that will enable me to select an area in a table (using the mouse), something similar to this script - http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/.

What I need to do is to select some td's with an identical area effect as used in the imgareaselect above, and manipulate the containing data. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#option-filter) you should be able to do something like this:

```
$('table').selectable({
    filter: 'td'
});
```